# Socket.io event listeners are triggered in my React class component spontaneously, with no server output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, jsx

I'm trying to implement some socket.io code in my React class component, but it doesn't seem to be working properly. My code looks like this:

```
class foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      socket: io("localhost:5000")
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.socket.on("event", console.log("event logged."))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I load up the React page in Chrome and open the dev tools console, I immediately see a "event logged." message. Any ideas on why this is happening? No server is running, so I'm confused as to why the socket event is triggered.

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to pass a function as second argument to `socket.on`,

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.state.socket.on("event", (data) => {console.log("event logged.")});
  }
```